# using bash sed to replace file name variables in file

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to find and replace in index.html the strings "js/main.js" and "js/main.min.js?YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" with a new "js/main.min.js?YYYYMMDDHHMMSS" using the below:

```
File='js/main.js'
MinFile='js/main.min.js'

datestr=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
echo sed -i.bak 's,\"'"$File"'\"|\"'"$MinFile"'\?.*?\",\"'"$MinFile"'?'"$datestr"'\",g' index.html
errorMsg=$(sed -i.bak 's,\"'"$File"'\"|\"'"$MinFile"'\?.*?\",\"'"$MinFile"'?'"$datestr"'\",g' index.html)
```

however its not matching on the "js/main.js" and "js/main.min.js?YYYYMMDDHHMMSS"

Comment: Should Match the src attributes in: <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.min.js?1234567890"></script>

Comment: Also Tried with failure:       echo ssed -i.bak "s,\"$File\"|\"$MinFile\?.*?\",\"$MinFile?$datestr\",g" index.html
errorMsg=$(sed -i.bak "s,\"$File\"|\"$MinFile\?.*?\",\"$MinFile?$datestr\",g" index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is how the syntax is parsed with escape characters:

- the ? should not be escaped
- the pipe should be escaped
- anyscroll brackets should be escaped

See [bash sed command failing to find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670973/bash-sed-command-failing-to-find-and-replace)
for what led to my solution.

The sed command ended up looking like this and working as expected in bash:

```
$(sed -i "s,\"$File\"\|\"$MinFile?[0-9]\{14\}\",\"$MinFile?$datestr\",g" index.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

you maybe want think about the next `perl` script.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_file(\*DATA);
$html->no_expand_entities(1);

my $now = strftime "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime;
foreach my $script ($html->find_by_tag_name('script')) {
    $script->{src} = "js/main.min.js?$now" if( $script->{src} =~ m{^(js/main.js|js/main.min.js)} );
}
print $html->as_HTML(undef, "\t");

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/nomain.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The "js/main.js" script is used here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

will print

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/main.min.js?20130520221648" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/nomain.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The "js/main.js" script is used here</body>
</html>
```

so changes all main.js in the `<script...` but not in the text...

Answer (score 0):

You have :

```
errorMsg=$(sed -i.bak 's,.$foo.,.$bar.,g' file)
```

if you want to use the shell variable in your sed, you should use `"` (double quote) instead of `'` single quote. shell-var won't be expanded between single quotes.

try something like:

```
errorMsg=$(sed -i.bak "s,$File..$MinFile...,...$datestr...,g" index.html)
```

Comment: yes .. saw that in my search as a common issue .. but notice the variables are wrapped in double quotes: echo evaluates to sed -i.bak s,"js/main.js"|"js/main.min.js\?.*?","js/main.min.201305201450000",g index.html

Comment: The following also does not work:       echo ssed -i.bak "s,\"$File\"|\"$MinFile\?.*?\",\"$MinFile?$datestr\",g" index.html
errorMsg=$(sed -i.bak "s,\"$File\"|\"$MinFile\?.*?\",\"$MinFile?$datestr\",g" index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
datestr=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
sed -ir "s/js\/(main.min.js|main.js)?(\?[0-9]*|)?/js\/main.min.js\?$datestr/g" index.html
```

input:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script> <script src="js/main.min.js?1234567890"></script>
```

output:

```
<script src="js/main.min.js?20130520143027"></script> <script src="js/main.min.js?20130520143027"></script>
```

Comment: input: <script src="js/main.js"></script> <script src="js/main.min.js?1234567890"></script> output: <script src="js/main.min.js?20130520101010"></script> <script src="js/main.min.js?20130520101010"></script>

Comment: I don't want to just replace dates generally I want to replace a specific reference to a specific file with a minified version and add a hash of the date time as a query parameter