# bash sed command failing to find and replace

Tags: bash, sed

I can not get the following bash sed commands to find and replace as it fails to match:

```
$ sed -i.bak 's,\"js/lj.main.min.js\?\d{14}\","js/lj.main.min.js?20130521080532",g' index.html
```

or

```
$ sed -i.bak 's,\"js/lj\.main\.min\.js\?\d{14}\","js/lj.main.min.js?20130521080532",g' index.html
```

On a text file including:

```
<script src="js/lj.main.min.js?20130520120515"></script>
```

Should Change to:

```
<script src="js/lj.main.min.js?20130521080532"></script>
```

The regex itself works when I try it in http://fiddle.re/m7x56

so whats up?

Comment: That causes it to error with:
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression works for me:

```
's,"js/lj\.main\.min.\js?[0-9]\{14\}","js/lj.main.min.js?20130521080532",g'
```

Note that there are many versions of regular expression libraries. Some features (`\d`) might not be supported, backslashing of some special characters can be different (`{}`, `?` etc.)